R Setting up an if statement inside a for loop
I am extremely new to learning coding so please be patient with me.
I have a list made up of two data frames and I need to add a value into a new column col3 based on another column col1. I apologize if it's something obvious, but I just started a week ago.
t <- c(130, 128, 116, 124, 133, 134, 118, 126, 114, 127, 141, 138, 128, 140, 137, 131, 120, 128, 139, 135)
p <- c(114, 98, 113, 99, 107, 116, 113, 111, 119, 117, 101, 119, 130, 122, 106, 106, 124, 102, 117, 113)
tp_df <- data.frame(t, p)
b <- c( 138, 135, 147, 117, 152, 134, 114, 121, 131, 130)
a <- c( 105, 136, 123, 130, 134, 143, 135, 139, 120, 124)
ba_df <- data.frame(b, a)
bp <- list(tp_df, ba_df)

So far, I've managed to get to this point, but the resulting column is populated completely with TRUE instead of based on the value of column 1.
tp_df$Status <- character(20)
ba_df$P.status <- character(10)
bp
for (i in 1:length(bp)){
  if (bp$tp_df$p[i] <= 120) {
    bp$tp_df$Status[i] <- "FALSE"
}  else if(bp$tp_df$p[i] > 120){
      bp$tp_df$Status[i] <- "TRUE"
  }
}
bp

What I want is this
     p     t    Status
1    130   114  FALSE   
2    128   98   TRUE   
3    116   113  TRUE   

What I have is this
     p     t    Status
1    130   114  FALSE   
2    128   98   FALSE   
3    116   113  FALSE   

I figured it out after asking my sibling. The problem I was having was in the for statement.
I was using:
for (i in 1:length(bp))

The actual correct one was:
for (i in 1:length(bp$tp_df$p))

Thank you all for the help and for answering my first question

What should ne done with ba_df?

Also, your expected output does not match your condition. I suspect you want something like setNames(bp[[2L]], names(bp[[1L]])); lapply(bp, \(x) transform(x, Status = p < 129)) if your intention is to operate on both dfs. But the condition is unclear. Conditoned on column p?  And what?

One of the useful things about R is that most operations can be vectorized, or done without using for loops. I'd suggest taking a look at this intro to vectorization, and then this tutorial on apply functions. Friede's comment shows how this allows you to do what you want in 2 lines instead of 10.

Yes, you should vectorize, but you also should realize that your second "if" is useless, as all values which faile the first "if" will pass the second one.  Much simpler:  mydata[] <- TRUE ; if (otherdata[i] <=120) mydata[i] <- FALSE

BEWARE!!   The string "FALSE"  is NOT a logical FALSE .

@Friede I will be doing the same thing with ba_df and the condition is only applied to colum p and printed in Status

@Eonema For this activity, I have to use the for function. Would you know any resources for that?

@CarlWitthoft That managed to get it to work but it is only checking the first values. How would I get it to check the full list?

Try
setNames(bp[[2L]], names(bp[[1L]]))
lapply(bp, transform, Status = p <= 130))

A verbose for-loop:
for(k in seq(length(bp))) bp[[k]]["Status"] = bp[[k]][1L] <= 130L


It works, but do keep in mind that  ?transform  says "This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting arithmetic functions, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument transform can have unanticipated consequences."

I use transform and similar within regularly in mission-critical, production code with zero issue.

Yes, me too. And I will continue to do so. :)

@Parfait   .... yet    :-(  .
